# Fetch matching records from another table based on condition and update records status In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have two tables: `OrderItems` as (#tempshopifyItemsWithLocation)

`OrderItems` table:

| Id | OrderMasterId | SPC | Barcode | Desc | Size/Color | Qty | TID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 911 | 1065832 | 10259795 | Brown Waistcoat | S / Brown | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 911 | 1065832 | 10259795 | Brown Three Piece | S / Brown | 1 | 2 |
| 103 | 911 | 1066602 | 10369982 | Grey Three Piece | S / Grey | 1 | 3 |
| 104 | 911 | 1066602 | 10369982 | Grey Suit | S / Grey | 1 | 4 |
| 105 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 5 |
| 106 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 6 |
| 107 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 7 |

[image: OrderItems Table Image]

and `Stock` table:

| Id | ItemBarcode | ItemLocation | Desc | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10259795 | Location-1 | 1065832 | Available |
| 2 | 10259795 | Location-2 | 1065832 | Available |
| 3 | 10369982 | Location-3 | 1066602 | Available |
| 4 | 10369982 | Location-4 | 1066602 | NotAvailable |
| 5 | 10425756 | Location-5 | Perfume | Available |
| 6 | 10425756 | Location-6 | Perfume | Available |
| 7 | 10457815 | Location-7 | Shoes | Available |

[image: Stock Table Image]

Here is my SQL query:

```
DECLARE @findPigeonholeId int = 0;
DECLARE @findPigeonholeBarcod varchar(25);
DECLARE @ShopifyItemId int = 0;
DECLARE @ShopifyOrderItemIdentity int = 0;

DECLARE @cnt int = 0;
DECLARE @TtlCnt int = 0; 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempFoundData', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempFoundData

CREATE TABLE #tempFoundData 
(
    Id int,
    PigeonholeBarcode varchar(25),
    TId int
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempshopifyItemsWithLocation','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation

SELECT TOP (20)
    s.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemBarcode) AS TId  
INTO
    #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation  
FROM
    tbl_Shopify_OrdersItems s
WHERE
    OrderMasterId = @OrderMasterId --* in this case OrderMasterId =911*

SET @TtlCnt  = 0; 
SET @TtlCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation);
                    
WHILE @cnt < @TtlCnt
BEGIN
    SET @findPigeonholeId = 0;
    SET @findPigeonholeBarcod = NULL;
    SET @ShopifyItemId = 0; 
    SET @ShopifyOrderItemIdentity = 0;

    SELECT TOP (1) 
        @findPigeonholeId = Id,
        @findPigeonholeBarcod = PigeonHoleBarcode 
    FROM
        tbl_Stock 
    WHERE 
        ItemBarcode = (SELECT ItemBarcode 
                       FROM #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation 
                       WHERE TId = (@cnt + 1)) 
      AND CompanyId = @Temp_CompanyId 
      AND (Active = 1 OR Active IS NULL)

    SELECT @ShopifyItemId = (@cnt + 1)

    SELECT @ShopifyOrderItemIdentity = Id 
    FROM #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation 
    WHERE TId = (@cnt + 1)

    IF @findPigeonholeId > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tbl_Stock 
        SET Active = 0, OrderMasterId= @OrderMasterId, 
            ShopifyOrderItemId = @ShopifyOrderItemIdentity
        WHERE Id = @findPigeonholeId

        INSERT INTO #tempFoundData (Id, PigeonholeBarcode, TId) 
        VALUES (@findPigeonholeId, @findPigeonholeBarcod, @ShopifyItemId)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempFoundData (Id, PigeonholeBarcode, TId) 
        VALUES (0, 'N/A', @ShopifyItemId)
    END

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

SELECT 
    tbc.Id, tbc.ItemBarcode, tbc.SPCode,
    tbc.OrderMasterId, tbc.Desc, tbc.SizeColor,
    tbc.Qty, tdf.PigeonholeBarcode AS Location,
    tdf.Id AS PId 
FROM 
    #tempshopifyItemsWithLocation tbc
INNER JOIN
    #tempFoundData tdf ON tbc.TId = tdf.TId
```

Result:

| Id | OrderMasterId | SPC | Barcode | Desc | Size/Color | Qty | TID | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 911 | 1065832 | 10259795 | Brown Waistcoat | S / Brown | 1 | 1 | Location-1 |
| 102 | 911 | 1065832 | 10259795 | Brown Three Piece | S / Brown | 1 | 2 | Location-2 |
| 103 | 911 | 1066602 | 10369982 | Grey Three Piece | S / Grey | 1 | 3 | Location-3 |
| 104 | 911 | 1066602 | 10369982 | Grey Suit | S / Grey | 1 | 4 | N/A |
| 105 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 5 | Location-5 |
| 106 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 6 | Location-6 |
| 107 | 911 | Perfume | 10425756 | Perfume | N/A | 1 | 7 | N/A |

[image: Result Of Above Query]

**Explanation**

I have two tables: `orderitems` and `stock` table. When I run this query, it takes the first row from `#tempshopifyItemsWithLocation` (`OrderItems`) table and search its status (available) barcode in `Stock` table.

- If found, then it will update status of record as `NotAvailable` and insert Id, Location of that row into temporary table `#tempFoundData`.
- If not found, then it will insert 0,'N/A' into `#tempFoundData`.

This query is working fine for few rows but I want to simplify this query and increase performance.

**QUESTION:** how I can simplify the query and increase performance?

Comment: This is a classic stock picking thing, but your version is weird, because there should generally be a stock amount? Here one row just takes a whole stock row?

Comment: Did you not just post this a day or two ago? And was told not to post images?

Comment: I did not post data in old post, Thats why I deleted old post. so in this post I posted data as a table.

Comment: @siggemannen I assume every stock row as 1 qty. it was requirment. Now I want to improve my query. could you please help how to achieve this with CTE Or any other medtod ?

Comment: @siggemannen every item in stock has different location(pigeonhole). So to track record of every items pigeonhole record, I hade to treat every row as single qty.